# Finite-exponent abelian groups

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $G=\bigoplus_{i=1}^t{{\Bbb{Z}}_{p_i}^{n_i}}^{(\Lambda_i)}$ where each $\Lambda_i$ is a set (at least one of $\Lambda_i$ is infinite). Since $G_{\Bbb{Z}}$ is a finite-exponent abelian group, so for every subgroup $H$ of $G$, $G/H$ is a direct sum of cyclic abelian groups.  Now I have the following question:
**Does $G/H\hookrightarrow G$ (means $G/H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$)  where $H\leq G_{\Bbb{Z}}$?**

We remark that the answer of the above question is Yes, when $G$ is finitely generated. But I am trying to prove it in the case that $G$ is not finitely generated.

Every comment is welcome, if any….

Comment: Yes. $G$ is a finite direct sum of possibly infinite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for various primes $p$, and you can just argue one prime at a time.

Comment: What does $n_i(\Lambda_i)$ mean?  Some of the $G$'s should clearly be $G_{\mathbb Z}$'s, but I'm not sure which ones.  Also, presumably the quantification is "for some $H \le G_{\mathbb Z}$", right?

Comment: Sorry for delay to reply. in fact there is a typo in the structure of G. In fact, I mean $G=\oplus_{i=1}^{t}({\Bbb{Z}}_{{p_i}^{n_i}})^{(\Lambda_i)}$.Moreover, My question, is the following: Is it true that for every subgroup $H$ of $G$, the factor $G/H$  is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$?